# How can i reproduce this using subqueries?

Tags: sql, subquery

I have just started learning SQL and have been tasked to recreate this using sub queries however i have googled a bit and still can't understand how to do that. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
SELECT ORDER_NUMB, ORDER_DATE FROM BRIAN.ORDERS
INNER JOIN BRIAN.CUSTOMERS 
ON BRIAN.ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUMB=BRIAN.CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_NUMB
WHERE CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME = 'Peter' 
AND CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME = 'Johnson';
```

Comment: Have you tried to re-write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select the Peter Johnson customer in the subquery and filter on that.

```
SELECT ORDER_NUMB
    , ORDER_DATE 
FROM BRIAN.ORDERS
WHERE BRIAN.ORDERS.CUSTOMER_NUMB IN (SELECT BRIAN.CUSTOMERS.CUSTOMER_NUMB
                                FROM BRIAN.CUSTOMERS
                                WHERE CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME = 'Peter' 
                                AND CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME = 'Johnson')
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are right. Updated to use "IN"